# Node body not preserving HTML formatting?

Tags: wysiwyg, theming, nodes

The body area of my node is set to WYSIWYG. When I enter in HTML formatting (using the WYSIWYG buttons), it doesn't make it to the content type template:

```
print $node->content['body']['#value'];
```

Why doesn't the HTML come through? How can I print the node body to the page and preserve the HTML formatting? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input format is likely "Filtered HTML", or something other than "Full HTML". Check the input format (below the body textarea when editing the node).

Comment: Hmm... I have a custom editor profile that I'm using. I just checked its settings though. I don't see a filtered/full HTML toggle anywhere. Where is that setting? Thanks!

Comment: You are most likely looking at the wrong place. You have to check the input filter. Make sure it's not stripping the html code. I always create a Full HTML filter with no filters attached to get this working.

Comment: I see Input Formats... but no Input Filter. Where should I be looking?!

Comment: Wait. Nevermind. You're right it was a filter! Turned that bad boy off and voila!